# Use a different foreign key with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

In short: **I want to create a Factory that uses an association with a specified foreign_key and primary key.**

In details:

These are the models I am using:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :municipality, :foreign_key => :municipality_code, :primary_key => 'code'
  ...
end

class Municipality < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, :foreign_key => 'municipality_code', :primary_key => 'code'
  ...
end
```

I tried to create the factory in this way:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :event do 
    sequence(:name){|n| "Event-#{n}"}
    ...
    municipality 
  end
end
```

but it does not make use of the foreign_key **municipality_code** defined in Event and of the primary key **code** defined in Municipality.
Is there a way to specify a different foreign key and primary key when creating an association with FactoryGIrl ?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

the way i solved it was managing the relationship myself.  not sure if this is the best answer, but it works for me.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :event do
    sequence(:name){|n| "Event-#{n}"}
  end
  factory :municipality do 
    after(:create) do |m, eval|
      # create one or many here...
      FactoryGirl.create(:event, municipality_code: m.code)
    end
  end
end
```